# Outlook Web Access constantly refreshes some e-mails in Inbox

Tags: windows-7, outlook-web-access

O have a Office 365 user. When this user is accessing Outlook Web Access, the top 10-20 mails in the Inbox starts flickers as if refreshing.

Note: for other folders the behaviour is normal.

Troubleshooting tried till now :

- Another user account login to check if user account has problem or system, but for other users also the same issue happens, which means system issue.
- Formatted the PC clean and installed OS windows 7 bit 32 version, but still issue exists
- Tried with other browsers but other browsers also gives the same flickering problem
- Checked if refreshing the URL but found it's not refreshing the URL or F5 key got pressed but it is not pressed
- Checked installed programs or applications after formatting also but nothing found
- For other URL's other than OWA there is no flickering issue, flickering occurs only for OWA and that too inbox folder and no other folder.logged this user on another PC to check if mail account problem but on other PC the OWA works fine so again it makes confirm that this is PC issue.

Please suggest some more troubleshooting steps if someone has resolved this issue before.

Comment: Is there a rule present that does something to the email in a continuous loop? Is the mail downloading, aka: refreshing new mails at the bottom?

Comment: Is there a rule present that does something to the email in a continuous loop?
another user account login to check if user account has problem or system, but for other users also the same issue happens, which means system issue.
Is the mail downloading, aka: refreshing new mails at the bottom?
new mails getting received and bottom mails wont refresh,only inbox the top 10-20 mails in the inbox starts flickers as if refreshing.This happens randomly, rest all it remains normal

Answer (score 2):

We just had this same issue, was fixed by setting the correct time and date on the client PC!